# Chrome-extension top and bottom of page not covered by CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome-extension, where I am changing the background in CSS:

```
body {
 background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
}
```

[image]

As you can see there is a white line at the top and bottom, how can I cover the whole background?

Comment: These are hardcoded borders displayed in Windows that you can't style. There was a short time span when the borders weren't displayed but it caused some problems so the change was reverted. The [underlying bug](https://crbug.com/824963) seems to be fixed but the borders are still displayed (in Windows, at least) so you could report that.

Comment: It'll be fixed in Chrome 74 (currently Canary) thanks to https://crrev.com/c/1444275

Answer (score -1):

```
body { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255); height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

Comment: didn't help, that made the window very, very small.

Comment: Try it again I have added some height and width.

Comment: I added the height and weight myself before, it's still the same :)